# Why exposed filter doesn't appear, when ajax is off in block view

Tags: views

I have a view as a block and I am using the exposed filter for content.I need a exposed filter value in the url but due to ajax ON its value doesn't pass to url, when ajax OFF then exposed filter is not appear. Please give me solution. how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because it is not a page. If you notice on page view, with ajax off, you will see a parameter passes through the url.

```
/example?something=yes
```

If you go to that url directly, it automatically filters your value.

Since blocks are not pages (do not have urls), you cannot do that. Therefore, reloading the block with AJAX is the only option for exposed filters in blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Views Block Exposed Filter Block" module to display the exposed filters as block for blocks and you can still have ajax on filtering.